# Secure communication between Objective-C application and MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I built an application in an objective c that performs user registration into DataBase (MYSQL) using PHP with METHOD - GET.
Is there any way for me to know if the received parameters came through the app and not via computer or manually?
I mean, anyone can discover the address of the server running the PHP code and embed
some manually parameters as: reg.php?name=someuser&pass=password.

Comment: 1. you should not register via GET; 2. basically you cannot, because any HTTP request can be edited in order to look like a "valid" one. 3. why bother where does the registration come from?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that yes, this is a security vulnerability.

**Resolving this security vulnerability via $_POST Method**

If you were to use the `$_POST` method instead, `name` and `pass` would be passed in the document's headers; going undetected in the URL. Then your web application could test for the presence of these variables, which would allow you to reject users who try to access the script from outside of your `Obj-C` app.

Better yet, also include a security token or hash parameter in the `$_POST` method, and test for the presence of that in your web application. On top of this, don't forget to *clean* your input before you allow it to touch your database, as an extra safety precaution.

**Fixing further security issues & vulnerabilities**

- The web application might use HTTPS.
- Should check for the presence of other environment variables to indicate if the client is accessing your website from the Obj-C environment.

Comment: You can make requests with POST body in many ways [e.g. cURL], so that wouldn't change anything.

Comment: That doesn't change that the variables go under the radar when they are out of the URL. This is the first level of security, that works in addition to further methods, not a be-all-end-all security fix.

Comment: `POST` isn't a bit more secure than `GET`. When using `POST`, the parameters are not passed in the header, as you said, but in the body of the HTTP stream. It's fairly easy to read an unencrypted HTTP stream using tools like WireShark. If you want anything secure, use HTTPS! It's quite simple to setup an SSL Server and you can use a self-signed certificate to avoid further costs.

Comment: I don't think that it is in dispute. But POST is definitely more secure, by the logic that it is LESS INSECURE than posting all the variable names for any Joe Bloggs script kiddie. POST is security, but it happens to be the least secure option. I agree that HTTPS is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has some kind of secret token and you use HTTPS with certificate validation then it's less likely to be a problem.

Remember that the contents of your application can be read by the user if they're determined, and the contents of your API calls can be intercepted and examined with a [proxy application](http://www.websecurify.com/desktop/proxy.html) if you're not careful to validate the SSL endpoint against known-good certificates.

Normally registrations are sent via POST, not GET.

You can either transmit the secret directly, as a sort of proof that you're using the Objective-C application, or to make it harder to discover, then by signing your request using something like SHA256 where that secret is a salt.